# Emerald installed but doesn't show in software center or synaptic?

Tags: 11.10, installation, software-center, synaptic, emerald

I installed Emerald using instructions from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870792); I've have had a nice play with it but would now like to remove it. The package doesn't show in software centre or synaptic and is now causing me a little headache as I can't seem to Google a solution, if I'm completely honest, I'm a little unsure of the install directory (to use `make` then `make uninstall`). I'm obviously new to Linux and I'm sure by now that's blatant so my apologies if the answer is an easy one, I've been using (various flavours) Linux for about a month and have been a windows user for I don't know how long; I'm not illiterate, I'm simply new to Linux so any advice here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

Thank you very much for replying so quick. The code you provided just gave me not found errors for emerald but thanks for pointing me in the direction of checkinstall; basically I run the same [code](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870792) as before and replaced `make install` with `sudo checkinstall` this reinstalled the package and created a .deb file; I can now upgrade/remove the package in software centre or synaptic.

thanks for your advice.

Comment: If you compile anything in future, look into using the checkinstall tool to make a deb and install into the package managers system for easy removal.

Comment: See the bottom of this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870792&page=3

Answer (score 1):

What you did is to compile and install from the source code. When you do that it won't appear on Synaptic or Software Center, so as the answer above says, you have to `sudo make uninstall` in order to uninstall it, from the same folder where the source code is (in a terminal).

There are ways to create a `deb` package from the source code so you can install it as any other deb package and uninstall it as well.

Answer (score 0):

His code is questionable, but try these:

```
cd ~/emerald-0.9.4
make uninstall
make clean
make distclean
```

If that doesn't work, I posted on his thread asking him how to uninstall. You can check here to see if he says anything: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11628870#post11628870